# Declare protocol conformance in objective-c protocol forward-declaration

Tags: objective-c, protocols, objective-c-protocol

Assume a class has been defined like this in `OriginalObject.h`:

```c
@protocol OriginalDelegate;

@interface OriginalObject : NSObject  {}
@property (nullable, nonatomic, weak) id<OriginalDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol OriginalDelegate <NSObject>
// … delegate method declarations …
@end
```

Now, in `ExtendedObject.h`, I want to do this:

```c
#import "OriginalObject.h"

@protocol ExtendedDelegate;

@interface ExtendedObject : OriginalObject {}
@property (nullable, nonatomic, weak) id<ExtendedDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol ExtendedDelegate <OriginalDelegate>
// … additional delegate method declarations …
@end
```

Attempting this gives me the following warning on the `@property … delegate;` line of `ExtendedObject.h`:

```
Property type 'id<ExtendedDelegate> _Nullable' is incompatible with type 'id<OriginalDelegate> _Nullable' inherited from 'OriginalObject'
```

It appears that the compiler doesn't know `ExtendedDelegate` will conform to `OriginalDelegate`. Moving the full protocol declaration above the `ExtendedObject` interface in `ExtendedObject.h` resolves the warning:

```c
#import "OriginalObject.h"

@protocol ExtendedDelegate <OriginalDelegate>
// … additional delegate method declarations …
@end

@interface ExtendedObject : OriginalObject {}
@property (nullable, nonatomic, weak) id<ExtendedDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

What I'd like to know is… **is there any way to tell the compiler *in the forward-declaration* that `ExtendedDelegate` will conform to `OriginalDelegate`** (enabling use of something more like the first version of `ExtendedObject.h` above)?

---

Neither of the following attempts at such a forward-declaration seem to be valid syntax:

```
@protocol ExtendedDelegate <OriginalDelegate>;
@protocol ExtendedDelegate : OriginalDelegate;
```

Comment: I’m confused. You have four protocols, ExtendedProtocol, OriginalProtocol, ExtendedDelegate, and OriginalDelegate. How exactly do they all relate?

Comment: Whoops, thanks for catching this. There should only be two: `OriginalDelegate` and `ExtendedDelegate`. Edited.

Comment: Okay I get it now! No, a `@protocol` or `@class` forward declaration is a bare name. It simply means, “trust me, this will turn out to be the name of a protocol / class.” You don’t get to say anything at all _about_ the protocol or class; that’s what the declaration is for.

Comment: You can extend class after protocol definition.